# Using the Onesignal Api "ADDITIONAL DATA" field

Tags: php, onesignal

I use Onesignal notifications for the app.
I don't have a problem sending the notifications but wanted to send these notifications using API help and this library.

[php-onesignal library](https://github.com/CarlosWGama/php-onesignal)

The notifications I sent must be opened on the relevant page in the application. For this reason, I do not know how to write the URL in the code section below.

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php');
use CWG\OneSignal\OneSignal;

$appID = '92b9c6bb-89d2-4cbc-8862-a80e4e81a251';
$authorizationRestApiKey = 'MWRjMTg2MjEtNTBmYS00ODA4LWE1M2EtM2YyZjU5ZmRkNGQ5';
$deviceID = '69aeecc1-7b58-44d1-8000-7767de437adf';
$api = new OneSignal($appID, $authorizationRestApiKey);

$retorno = $api->notification->setBody('Ola')
                            ->setTitle('Titulo')
                            ->addDevice($deviceID)
                            ->send();
```

I entered the addTag section as in the Onesignal panel, but I could not run it.

```
$retorno = $api->notification->setBody('Ola')
                            ->setTitle('Titulo')
                            ->addTag('url', 'http://www.example.com/news/testtitle')
                            ->send();
print_r($retorno);
```

[image]
How can I use it here in the Url section of the **"ADDITIONAL DATA"** field?
Can I solve this problem with **addTag?**

Answer (score 0):

The following will send a notification with the $data['data'] as additional, as you want.

```
$data = [
    'headings' => ['en' => 'Case 123'],
    'contents' => ['en' => 'Case assigned ' . date('d-m-Y H:i')],
    'data'     => [
       'type'      => 'new',
       'user_id' => 123,
       'url' => 'http://www.example.com/news/testtitle'
    ],
];

OneSignal::sendNotificationCustom([
    'app_id'            => 1234,
    'api_key'           => abcd,
    'included_segments' => ['All'],
    'headings'          => $data['headings'],
    'contents'          => $data['contents'],
    'data'              => $data['data'],
]);
```

Comment: I can already send notifications. I asked how can I set the url tag.

Comment: read carefully, the 'data' has the 'type' and 'user_id' keys which are sent in the additional data.  in your case, it would be 'url' => 'http://example.com'

Comment: Call to undefined method CWG\OneSignal\OneSignal::sendNotificationCustom()